# Android LocationManager requestLocationUpdates in a WearableListenerService

Tags: android, wear-os, locationmanager, android-wear-data-api

I'm wondering how (if possible) to successfully run a `requestLocationUpdates` for my `LocationManager` inside a short-lived service - in this case an Android `WearableListenerService`.

For example, I have a service that runs when the wearable devices sends a message saying it needs an update.  Part of this update is to query an external API for some data based on the user's current location.  If no "last known" location is returned from `getLastKnownLocation` I am registering for `requestLocationUpdates` from the location manager to get the current location of the device and then will do my thing.

However, the short-lived service exists and is destroyed before the location manager receives the location change event and thus the callback listener doesn't fire, or I get ["sending message to a Handler on a dead thread" errors like this](https://gist.github.com/cpjolicoeur/731efdee90243f02e56e).

My question, is can I force this service to more or less block until a location has been found and the `onLocationChanged` callback fires before the exit (`onDestroy`) is called?

Or, what is the proper/correct mechanism for handling this?

Comment: How is your WearableListenerService started?

Comment: Via the MessaeApi with a message sent from the wearable device

Comment: Did you figure out any good solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

One approach would be to start an IntentService, from within your WearableListenerService. In the IntentService, you can send your location request in onHandleIntent() and you can block on that till you get your response (with a timeout hopefully); since onHandleIntent is called on a worker thread, you wouldn't be causing any issues. When you get the result back, you can update your wearable app; this approach seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: I guess I'm more curious about the "blocking mechanism."   Whether the blocking happens in a secondary IntentService `onHandleIntent()` or inside my existing WearableListenerService, I still need to block while the request location updates happens.  What is the preferred/prescribed mechanism for blocking in this manner until an asynchronous callback can be run?

Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding your approach.

Comment: You should block inside your IntentService#onHandleIntent() since that would be on a worker thread; that is the whole point behind starting an IntentService.

Comment: Block how? What mechanism is used to actually block that thread? Just a simple wait timeout?